# How do i copy a file to destination wildcard folders?

Tags: linux

I need to copy a file from one folder to any folder what matches a pattern however its not working and I'm going nuts,

[image]

cp /usr/local/etc/suricata/urlhaus.rules /usr/local/etc/suricata/suricata_*/rule/urlhaus.rules

cp: No match.

[2.4.5-RELEASE][admin@pf-testy.localdomain]/usr/local/etc/suricata: ls -l

-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel     3205 Apr 18 00:10 classification.config

-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel     4258 Mar 19 19:34 classification.config.sample

-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel       32 Apr 18 00:10 community-rules.tar.gz.md5

-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel       33 Apr 18 00:10 emerging.rules.tar.gz.md5

-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel     1247 Apr 18 00:10 reference.config

-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel     1375 Mar 19 19:34 reference.config.sample

drwxr-xr-x  2 root  wheel      512 Apr 13 19:16 rules.local

-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel       18 Apr 18 00:10 rulesupd_status

-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    70224 Mar 19 19:34 suricata.yaml

-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    70224 Mar 19 19:34 suricata.yaml.sample

drwxr-xr-x  3 root  wheel      512 Apr 16 19:22 suricata_33606_hn0

drwxr-xr-x  3 root  wheel      512 Apr 16 19:22 suricata_55074_hn1

drwxr-xr-x  3 root  wheel      512 Apr 13 19:34 suricata__hn0

-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel     1644 Mar 19 19:34 threshold.config

-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel     1644 Mar 19 19:34 threshold.config.sample

-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel  8307916 Apr 18 17:42 urlhaus.rules

Comment: Please see this QA from Stack Overflow: https://stackoverflow.com/q/195655/6216002

Comment: Please copy/paste text from console into your post rather posting images, Much easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
for i in /usr/local/etc/suricata/suricata_*; do
  cp /usr/local/etc/suricata/urlhaus.rules ${i}/rules/urlhaus.rules
done
```

Comment: [Copy the download rules rule to the interface folders
cp: /usr/local/etc/suricata/suricata_33606_hn0/rule/urlhaus.rules: No such file or directory
cp: /usr/local/etc/suricata/suricata_55074_hn1/rule/urlhaus.rules: No such file or directory
cp: /usr/local/etc/suricata/suricata__hn0/rule/urlhaus.rules: No such file or directory

done]

Comment: `#!/bin/sh

echo  Download the rules file


curl https://urlhaus.abuse.ch/downloads/ids/ > /usr/local/etc/suricata/urlhaus.rules


echo  Copy the download rules rule to the interface folders



for i in /usr/local/etc/suricata/suricata_*; do

  cp /usr/local/etc/suricata/urlhaus.rules ${i}/rule/urlhaus.rules
  
done


echo done`

Comment: I believe the issue is that the directories corresponding to suricata_*/rules do not exist. cp copies files -- it does not have the responsibility to create intermediate levels of directory. In addition, your screenshot shows "rules" but your text says "rule", as do both your comments to this answer.

Answer (score 0):

with CP you can copy multi-files but only one destination.
you need to use "xargs"

edit: the command is one line

`sudo echo /usr/local/etc/suricata/suricata_*/rule/urlhaus.rules | sudo xargs -n 1 cp -v /usr/local/etc/suricata/urlhaus.rules`

Comment: cp: /usr/local/etc/suricata/suricata_*/rule/urlhaus.rules: No such file or directory

Comment: @user407165, under "/usr/local/etc/suricata/suricata_*/rule/" you have folder "urlhaus.rules" if yes and it's the same in all others "suricata_*" same path after that so you need to = sudo echo /usr/local/etc/suricata/suricata_*/rule/urlhaus.rules | sudo xargs -n 1 cp -v /usr/local/etc/suricata/urlhaus.rules/